# Use FuelManager instance instead of global config for requests

Tags: kotlin, fuel

fuel docs mention the possibility to create a FuelManager instance for not-global config:

> Create separate managers using FuelManager()

However I haven't found a way to use an instance of FuelManager instead of the global one in making a request. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FuelManager` offers functions to make HTTP calls directly, so you can/should use the (configured) instance.
**Note:** Avoid e.g. `Fuel#get` since then you'd use the global `FuelManager`config.